# How to swap vim commands

Tags: vim

There are `gf` and `gF` commands in vim.
I want to use gf runs the exactly `gF` doing, and vice versa.

Does there any way can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this vim script to your .vimrc:

```
:noremap gf gF
:noremap gF gf
```